# How to display sorting methods from PROC CONTENTS in SortedBy field?

Tags: sas

I am trying to show that my data has been sorted within my PROC contents output. Within this output there is an attribute called "SortedBy" and within that it shows how the contents were sorted (to the best of my knowledge).

My question is, how can I get my output to look like the below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
/*Not sorted*/
proc contents data = I.projects;
run;

/*Sorted*/
proc sort data = WORK.projects out = projects;
by REGION descending POL NAME;
run;
proc contents data = WORK.projects;
run;
```

Comment: Check the ODS options for proc contents by running ODS TRACE ON as the first statement in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Select the `SORTEDBY` output table; as @Bill mentioned a prior submit with `ODS TRACE ON` will list the output tables.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
  by descending make model type;
run;

ods select sortedby;

proc contents data=cars;
run;
```

Trace information appears in the SAS log

```
67   ods trace on;
68   proc contents data=cars;
69   run;


Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Attributes
Label:      Attributes
Template:   Base.Contents.Attributes
Path:       Contents.DataSet.Attributes
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       EngineHost
Label:      Engine/Host Information
Template:   Base.Contents.EngineHost
Path:       Contents.DataSet.EngineHost
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Variables
Label:      Variables
Template:   Base.Contents.Variables
Path:       Contents.DataSet.Variables
-------------

Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Sortedby
Label:      Sortedby
Template:   Base.Contents.Sortedby
Path:       Contents.DataSet.Sortedby
-------------
NOTE: PROCEDURE CONTENTS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.05 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds


70   ods trace off;
```

You can also retrieve the `SORTEDBY` data set attribute using the data step function `ATTRC`

```
data before (keep=sortedby);
  when = 'BEFORE';
  ds = open('cars');
  sortedby = attrc(ds,'SORTEDBY');
  ds = close (ds);
run;

* sort … ;

data after (keep=sortedby);
  when = 'AFTER';
  ds = open('cars');
  sortedby = attrc(ds,'SORTEDBY');
  ds = close (ds);
run;

data compare;
  set before after;
run;
```